# Different QuoteDocument using Connected APP REST API and Workbench / Interaction

Tags: apex, permissions, rest, security, quote

I've set up a autolaunched Flow, which creates a PDF based on a Quote Template. My connected APP use this Flow through the REST-API.

The output is an empty PDF with a Size of 2 KB. The same Flow, the same Input through the Workbench is successful.

It must be some kind of missing permsission, but i cannot figure it out. Any Idea why the same Call through the connected App has a different output?

The Flow itselft triggers an apex Code:

```
   public static void CreateQuoteDocumentFromPDF(List<Id> ids) {

    Blob renderedPDF;
    List<QuoteDocument> docs = new List<QuoteDocument>();
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        for (Id id : ids) {
            renderedPDF = Blob.valueOf('Unit.Test');
            QuoteDocument doc = new QuoteDocument(QuoteId = id, Document = renderedPDF);
            docs.add(doc);
        }
    } else {
        for (Id id : ids) {
            List<Quote_Generation_Settings__mdt> quoteSettings = [SELECT Quote_Template_Id__c FROM Quote_Generation_Settings__mdt WHERE QualifiedApiName  = 'Settings' LIMIT 1];
            if (quoteSettings.size()>0) {
                if (quoteSettings[0].Quote_Template_Id__c != null && quoteSettings[0].Quote_Template_Id__c != '') {
                    String quoteURL = '/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?resizeAutomatically=true&summlid=' + quoteSettings[0].Quote_Template_Id__c + '&id=' + id;
                    renderedPDF = new PageReference(quoteURL).getContentAsPDF();
                    QuoteDocument doc = new QuoteDocument(QuoteId = Id, Document = renderedPDF);
                    docs.add(doc);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if (docs != null) INSERT docs;

}
```

The Custom Settings is for setting the Quote Template which should be used, since QuoteTemplates cannot be searched using Apex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: The Blank Page is because of same Transaction in which the Quote was created and the PDF was generated. Solution was to mark the Function as `future(callout=true)`

Comment: But the same is working properly when invoked through Workbench. Not sure why.